# English text breaks in persian text

Tags: html, asp.net, tooltip, line-breaks, persian

I want to break line in persian text of tool tip,so I used this in ASP.NET:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="cut" runat="server" ToolTip="یک ;13#& دو"/>
```

but in returned html tool tip text changing to:

```
title="یک ;13#&amp; دو"
```

that cause line break to not work.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're typing `&#13;` correctly? I have added a text box and set a line break in its tooltip and it worked correctly: (ASP.Net 4.0 Webforms)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ToolTip="خط اول &#13; خط دوم"></asp:TextBox>
```

Copy and paste the line above and it should work correctly.

Comment: it breaks in html but not in browser output!

Comment: The break character is invisible in source view.

Comment: I know that,I say no break in tooltip result.

Comment: Which browser are you using? The tooltip result shows up fine in Firefox 21, Chrome 27 and IE10.

Comment: How can I change BlogeEngine.NET's comments default country?

Comment: please create a new question since this is not related to your current question.